# Number of available IP addresses per private IP address range

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, cidr

I have a problem with determining the correct number of available IP addresses per private IP address range for an AWS VPC for example.

Given that AWS allows assigning a range starting from a /16 block, I have the following available ranges. Given the fact they take 4 addresses away from me, this leaves me with the following ranges:

```
10.0.0.4 - 10.0.255.254
172.16.0.4 - 172.16.255.254
192.168.0.4 - 192.168.255.254
```

According to all calculators available on the internet, I get the same amount of IP addresses (65331). Nevertheless I've seen numerous recommendations to choose 10.0.0.0 as the address range, as it provides the highest number of IP addresses. Can somebody clarify this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I understand your question too well, but I will try to shed some light on what you are asking. AWS uses those 4 IPS for their internal routing and configuration of their network.

Example VPC Address Range: **10.0.0.0/16**

If you have this CIDR example, AWS takes the first 4 for their own resources of each **SUBNET** and you have access to the rest of these IPS in the given SUBNETS.

Now we can break that VPC down into smaller subnets so it can be used for different reasons such as the standard ( Pub / Private ).

Example Subnet : 10.0.0.0/27 = 32 IPS
32 - 4 = 28

AWS Also does not support .255(network broadcast address) of a subnet, so they take the last IP as well which gives you a total for 28 - 1 = 27 IPS for use.

Sources: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html

Comment: Hi, but this still leaves me with the same amount of IP addresses, no matter if I choose 10.0.0.0, 172.16.0.0 or 192.168.0.0, so I don't understand why 10.0.0.0 is recommended to use.

Comment: @Coiiin Since you only consider /16 block. For larger network, The ip starting from 10 can cover upto /8 block.

Comment: Usually, companies use 10.x block within their private network as a networking standard and thats why AWS recommends that. It is assuming you are creating your own private network.

Comment: @dtshack by your logic, AWS should recommend *against* that -- to reduce the likelihood of conflicts.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Yes, indeed! It is usually recommended against.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. It would not recommend as you would have your AWS development team coordinate with your on-prem networking to insure certain CIDR ranges are not overlapping within the AWS network. How do you think most companies migrate into AWS or have Hybrid solutions?

Comment: Again, I am not going fully into details as to what you have to do to set this up, just giving a general knowledge of what they make me assuming you are doing.

Comment: Anyone having a correct answer to my original question?

Comment: @Coiiin Use these for your references and I hope you at least upvote my answer as I mentioned why 10.x. https://serverfault.com/questions/52631/is-it-better-to-use-the-192-168-x-x-or-10-x-x-x-address-range-for-a-small-busine

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html